# change rename shortcut to return in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I've been trying to change my shortcuts to OS X style. I managed to alter super and control keys system wide but I’ve been having trouble changing to rename shortcut to Enter key. I’ve tried changing the accls in /home/.config/nautilus but it doesn’t seem to work and after I restart X session, pressing enter opens the file. what should I do?
(I'm running gnome Ubuntu 14.04 by the way)

Comment: Can you edit your post with the `/home/$USER/.config/nautilus/accels` content?

Comment: I think this works fine for up to Ubuntu 16. I'm now running Ubuntu 18 and this ceased to work. Help solving this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to this question over in [Keyboard Shortcut to Rename File in GUI (Other Than F2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696866/keyboard-shortcut-to-rename-file-in-gui-other-than-f2), including 14.04/16.04 (same solution) and 18.04 (newer solution).