# Keyboard Shortcut to Rename File in GUI (Other Than F2)

Tags: shortcut-keys, filename, productivity

I want to rename a file in GUI. I know I can either <kbd>RightClick</kbd> > `Rename` OR press <kbd>F2</kbd>, but I know in Chrome OS you can just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the Files app, and it will do that.

Is anything similar to this possible in Ubuntu? Is there any keyboard shortcut other than <kbd>F2</kbd> that will allow one to rename a file in GUI?

Or, if not, then is there a way for me to set a custom keyboard shortcut for this as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, like in Chrome OS? I know currently trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will only do the same thing as just typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

#### Specs

- **Make & Model**: Dell Inspiron N5010
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 15.04
- **File Manager**<sup>1</sup>: Files [the default one included in Unity]
- **GUI Environment**<sup>2</sup>: Unity

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't even think this matters, does it?

<sup>2</sup> Is it redundant to say "GUI Environment"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Gnome instead of Unity, but they should be the same (more or less).

Nautilus (a.k.a. Files) keeps its keyboard shortcuts in  `~/.config/nautilus/accels`

File Rename is listed there as:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Rename" "F2")
```

The `;` means that it is commented out and Nautilus uses the system default.

If you remove the `;` and change the line to:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Rename" "<Primary>Return")
```

Then File Rename will be changed to `Control-Enter`.

It seems that there is only one shortcut possible for each operation. Nautilus uses the last one listed.
So you can't have `F2` and `Control-Enter` at the same time.

In order for the changes to take effect you have to stop nautilus. Run the following from the commandline (before you make the change):

```
nautilus -q
```

---

Detailed steps (on request):

- open Files ('Nautilus')
- browse to directory `.config/nautilus` in your home directory
- if you don't see directories starting with a dot, press `<Ctrl>H` or in the preferences for Files ('Nautilus'), tick the box for displaying hidden files.
- right-click or double-click file `accels` so that it opens in an editor (likely `gedit`)
- Alternatively, hit `<Alt>F2` and give command: `gedit ~/.config/nautilus/accels`

Now we have the configuration file in an editor, we have to stop Files ('Nautilus') before we can make changes. Again, two ways of doing this:

- Option 1: open a terminal window (`Gnome Terminal`) and kill nautilus, by issuing command: `nautilus -q`. Your Files window(s) should all disappear
- Option 2: hit `<Alt>F2` and give command `nautilus -q`. Your Files window(s) should all disappear

Now Files ('Nautilus') has been stopped, we can make changes to its configuration files.

- In the editor, make the changes as listed above and save the file
- Exit the editor

If you now open Files ('Nautilus') again, your changes should take effect

---

Answers to foot notes:

1. It is relevant to specify the application you're having a problem with. In this case, it was the configuration of the application as opposed to a system setting that had to be modified to resolve this issue.
2. People will know what you mean by `GUI Environment`. It is however generally referred to as `GUI` or `Desktop` in this context.

Comment: By the way, a few questions: (1) What do you mean by "commented out"?

Comment: (2) What does `<primary>` mean? Nothing comes up if I search for that on Wikipedia.

Comment: (3) Damn, it'd be nice to have both `F2` and `Ctrl+Enter`. Still, it's just as nice to even just have `Ctrl+Enter`! :D

Comment: @SarahofGaia  (1)Commented out means that the line has no effect. The `;` tells Nautilus to ignore everything that follows it. Nautilus will then use its default setting, which is `F2`

Comment: @SarahofGaia (2) `<Primary>` is the GTK name for the Control key. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168516/121614

Comment: @SarahofGaia (3) It might be possible to bind a function to multiple key combination, but I don't know enough about the configuration syntax to answer that.

Comment: (1) Oh, I see. Sort of like the `#` syntax for commenting in an HTML document, right?

Comment: (2) Ah, so correct me if I'm wrong, but then `Ctrl` is **not** a Windows-proprietary, nor has ever been a Windows-proprietary key label, correct?

Comment: (3) Neither do I. Lol. I'll just make do with having just `Ctrl+Enter`. ;)

Comment: @SarahofGaia (1) Comments in an HTML document are enclosed in `<!--` and `-->`, Bash and most configuration files use `#` to introduce a comment.  And, yes `;` has the same function as these comment delimiters in HTML (2) `Primary` is a GTK+ thing, for details see this post on [UL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168505/121614)

Comment: (1) Oh, yeah, you're right. Oops! Lol. I got that mixed up from Python. xD

Comment: (2) Didn't you already suggest that link above at [2015-11-12T20:07Z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696866/keyboard-shortcut-to-rename-file-in-gui-other-than-f2/697012?noredirect=1#comment1020700_697012)?

Comment: @SarahofGaia (2) Yes, you're right - same link. Still useful  ;-)  I do have another link for you though on Wikipedia -  [Modifier Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key)

Comment: Really, now. :3 Another link? You shouldn't have. °∪°

Comment: By the way, is the above directions supposed to be done in the file manager or the terminal? Sorry for being a doofus. °∩°

Comment: @SarahofGaia See amended instructions in the post.

Comment: By the way, Just as a bonus, could you answer a few more questions?

Comment: (1) The footnote questions.

Comment: (2) Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/AfO3NwK.png) abnormal or bad? :{

Comment: @SarahofGaia (1) I've answered your foot notes as well. (2) This is nothing to worry about. It very likely only happens when Nautilus is not running. A lot of GTK+ programs generate a lot of errors and warnings when run from the commandline. See the answers to this [post](http://askubuntu.com/q/422254/425630)

Comment: (1) Indeed, you have. Thank you. °◡° (2) Okay, I see.

Comment: **Followup to Footnote Responses**: (1) "People will know what you mean by `GUI Environment`." I realise now that technically it wasn't redundant since there are also TUI environments, not just GUI. (2) "It is however generally referred to as `GUI` or `Desktop` in this context." Isn't "desktop" most often used to refer to [the desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_metaphor)?

Comment: @SarahofGaia In 'colloquial speech' they are often used interchangeable. E.g. someone could ask you what GUI you are using and you could say that you are using the Gnome desktop of the XFCE desktop. Also see this [UL post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198134/121614)

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> worked for me in the *File Navigator*, 
but then you have to use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Bring BackSpace back to nautilus (3.18+) once and for all!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722125/bring-backspace-back-to-nautilus-3-18-once-and-for-all). We can use the same fix for Ubuntu 18.04+ (Nautilus 3.26+) to set the shortcut keys for rename.

1) Install Nautilus Python

```
apt-get install python-nautilus
```

2) Download Backspace-Back.py from [Nautilus-backspace](https://github.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace) and put it in ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/nautilus-python
mkdir ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riclc/nautilus_backspace/master/BackspaceBack.py ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/BackspaceBack.py
```

3) Make a copy of the file (or rename) for the purposes of making a new shortcut (or put it all in that one file).

```
cp BackspaceBack.py Rename.py
```

4) Edit Rename.py and modify the line in the file that starts with app.set_accels_for_action to the following:

```
app.set_accels_for_action( "view.rename", ["<control>Return"] )
app.set_accels_for_action( "view.open-item-new-tab", [] )
```

5) Restart Nautilus (killall nautilus)

Note that "open-item-new-tab" also has to be modified to free up the Control+Return key combination and then reassign it to "rename".

You can use this to change any shortcut in Nautilus. The complete list of current shortcuts and their defaults can be pulled from [the source code for Nautilus](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/src/nautilus-files-view.c) (search for `nautilus_application_set_accelerator`).